# Vim replacing with groups

Tags: vim, replace

I was trying to do the following replacement under vim:

```
"a": 1,
"b": 2,
"c": 3
```

to

```
"a": d["a"],
"b": d["b"],
"c": d["c"]
```

It seems that regex under vim is diff from normal regex. Could any one help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your file contains both the **colon** and the **fullwidth colon** and which makes the substitution a little bit difficult to handle.

If you type `ga` while the cursor is above the `:` character on the **first** and **second line** you will find that they **are not the same.**

In fact, for the first line you will get the **fullwidth colon**:

```
<：> 65306, Hexa ff1a, Octal 177432
```

and for the second & third line you will get the known **colon**:

```
<:>  58,  Hexa 3a,  Octal 072
```

In order to substitute both colons you can execute this command:

```
:%s/\v("\w+")\s*(:|%uFF1A)\s*\d+(,?)/\1: d[\1]\3/g
```

You can notice the ***`%uFF1A`*** in the second group which represents the fullwidth colon in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Some helpful people have even figured out a method of producing this kind of questions [automatically](https://github.com/reinderien/mimic). ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You may choose to use a recursive macro.**

On the first line, empty the q register

```
qqq
```

Start the q macro

```
qq
```

Do the job once and finish the macro by recalling itself (this is why you have to empty the q register first).

```
0yt:f ad[]<ESC>Pf]lC,<ESC>j0@q
```

Here, we :

- go to the first char
- yank to the column
- move until the next blank char
- insert after the cursor d[]
- exit insert mode
- paste before the cursor
- move to the ] char
- move again right
- replace the end of line with a comma
- exit insert mode
- prepare the next execution of the macro by going to the next line
- call again the macro

Then you stop editing the macro

```
q
```

And you execute it

```
@q
```

**You also can try this substitution**

```
:%s/^\("\S\{-}"\): \d\+\(,\?\)$/\1: d[\1]\2/
```

Answer (score -2):

```
%s/^\(.*\):.\{-\}\(,\|\)$/\1: d[\1]\2/
```

Lots of regex engines are different, I don't know that there's a "normal" regex; Vim is quite an old one, and parentheses need to be escaped to make groups `\(\)`, so do braces for match counts `\{\}`, and non-greedy matching is not supported with `.*?` and needs to be `.\{-\}`.

This matches

- anything from line start to a colon
- anything (non-greedy)
- a comma, or nothing, at the end of the line

and replaces with `group 1: d[group 1]group2`

Comment: @Meninx yes, of course - [screenshot before](http://i.imgur.com/TBwuvbK.png) and [screenshot after](http://i.imgur.com/7s7mS4l.png).  Have you tried clearly explaining what you want to communicate?

Comment: Read my answer you will figure out. You haven't copied the exact lines as the OP did in the question.

Comment: @Meninx - When I just copy/paste OP's example, it pastes as plain ascii and this answer works as is. I first resorted to Powershell to get the actual unicode character. Setting the encoding in vim to utf-8 at least showed the first colon as a "special" character. Is your encoding for new buffers always utf-8? That would explain the difference.

Comment: You can try to select the colon of OP's example and you will know that he is using utf-8 encoding.